# RMTP Broadcasting from Codename One

Tags: codenameone

Is there any ready or almost ready solution to broadcast live video/audio content from a Codename One app to a RMTP server?

Thank you

Comment: Not that I'm aware of but I'm not very familiar with this field so it's possible there's something simple in the native platforms that we can wire to that I'm unfamiliar with.